# Grouping an array by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

So i have this data structure:

```
const Array= [
  {
    court: 'court1',
    judge: 'judge1'
  },
  {
    court: 'court1',
    judge: 'judge3'
  },
  {
    court: 'court1',
    judge: 'judge2'
  },
  {
    court: 'court1',
    judge: 'judge1'
  },
  {
    court: 'court2',
    judge: 'judge1'
  },
  {
    court: 'court2',
    judge: 'judge2'
  }
]
```

and should to modify to like this:

```
Obj = {
   court1: ["judge1", "judge3", "judge2"],
   court2: ["judge1", "judge2"]
}
```

So finally i find some decision and edit myself like this:

```
let result = Array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.court] = acc[cur.court] || []
    if (acc[cur.court].indexOf(cur.judge) === -1) {
      acc[cur.court].push(cur.judge)
    }
    return acc
}, Object.create(null))
console.log(result)
```

But i try to understand WHY the line `acc[cur.court] = acc[cur.court] || []` create a new object like this:

```
Obj = {
   court1: [],
   court2: []
}
```

Can you explain me please? And maybe you know more elegant decision?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `acc` is initially an empty object. Inside the `reduce` callback, the only properties that are ever assigned to it, with the line `acc[cur.court] = acc[cur.court] || []`, are arrays, and arrays are truthy.

If a property exists at `cur.court`, `acc[cur.court] || []` will evaluate to that property. Otherwise, it'll evaluate to an empty array. Then, it'll assign the result to `acc[cur.court]`.

A less confusing way of writing it, while doing the same thing, would be:

```
if (!acc[cur.court]) {
  acc[cur.court] = [];
}
```

The code looks pretty reasonable already, although I'd prefer using the `if` statement above, because it looks a bit less confusing.

Another option would be to [avoid `reduce` entirely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) when the accumulator is always the same object, as some would argue:

```
const result = {};
for (const { court, judge } of Array) {
  if (!result[court]) {
    result[court] = [];
  }
  result[court].push(judge);
}
```

(if possible, also change the `Array` variable name, maybe to `arr` or something. It's shadowing `window.Array`, which has potential for confusion and bugs)

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you very and wish you good luck)